# ECS Service resource not deploying successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am using cloudformation template to spin up a simple nginx web server using amazon ECS/ECR.
Reference here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights-Prometheus-Setup-nginx-ecs.html

My template.yaml creates the necessary resources (ALB/ECS Task Def/Target groups etc) and they are deployed successfully in my account. But when I tried to add ECS::Service resource, the stack is updating forever and ultimately times out. During this process, I could see ECS service and tasks in AWS console...I belive AWS attempts to bring up the task, but for whatever reason it could not and then it tries again and again.
It should be missing something during the stack creation but I am unable to figure out.

My template.yaml is below.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: ecs poc ui Fargate

Parameters:
  SubnetIds:
    Type: String

 ExportKeySuffixForSubnetInPrivateAZ1:
   Type: String
   Default: 'PrivateAZ1-ID'

ExportKeySuffixForSubnetInPrivateAZ2:
  Type: String
  Default: 'PrivateAZ2-ID'

AppNameForResources:
  Type: String
  Default: "demo-ecs-poc-ui"
  AllowedValues: [ "demo-ecs-poc-ui" ]


NetworkStackName:
  Type: String

ECSTaskDefinitionContainerPort:
  Type: String
  Default: ''

Image:
  Type: String

ServiceName:
  Type: String

ContainerPort:
  Type: String

ECSTaskDefinitionSecretsARN:
  Type: String
  Default: ''

ServiceHttpPort:
  Type: String
  Default: ''

Environment:
  Type: String

LoadBalancerTargetGroupProtocol:
  Type: String
  Default: HTTP
  AllowedValues:
  - HTTP
  - HTTPS

ServiceHttpsPort:
  Type: String
  Default: ''

VPC:
  Type: String

ListenerPath:
  Type: String

ListenerPriority:
  Type: String

Mappings:
  Env:
    dev:
    uppercase: DEV

Resources:
  ECSCluster:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
  Properties:
    ClusterName: !Sub ecs-${Environment}-${AWS::Region}-${ServiceName}-cluster
    ClusterSettings:
      - Name: containerInsights
        Value: enabled
    CapacityProviders:
      - FARGATE
    DefaultCapacityProviderStrategy:
      - CapacityProvider: FARGATE
        Weight: 4
        Base: 1

ECSTaskDefinition:
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
    Family: !Join ["-", [!Ref ServiceName, taskdef, !Ref Environment]]
    NetworkMode: awsvpc
    RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
    Cpu: !Ref CPU
    Memory: !Ref Memory
    ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt ECSTaskRole.Arn
    TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt ECSTaskRole.Arn
    ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: !Sub
          - "${TheServiceName}-${TheEnvironment}"
          - TheServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
            TheEnvironment: !Ref Environment
        Image: !Ref Image
        Environment:
          - Name: AWS_ENV
            Value: !Ref Environment
          - Name: AWS_REGION
            Value: !Ref AWS::Region
        PortMappings:
          - ContainerPort: '80'

ECSTaskRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName:
      !Sub
      - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-ecs-task-role"
      - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ 'ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com' ]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
    Path: /
    Policies:
      - PolicyName:
          !Sub
          - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-ecs-task-role-policy"
          - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
            TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress'
                - 'ec2:Describe*'
                - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer'
                - 'elasticloadbalancing:Describe*'
                - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer'
                - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets'
                - 'elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups'
                - 'elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth'
                - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets'
                - 'ecs:*'
                - 'ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability'
                - 'ecr:BatchGetImage'
                - 'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer'
                - 'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken'
                - 'iam:GetRole'
                - 'iam:PassRole'
                - 'cloudformation:List*'
              Resource: "*"

SecurityGroupForALB:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: !Sub 'Created for ALB of ${AppNameForResources} app on ${Environment}
```

env'
SecurityGroupIngress:
- IpProtocol: tcp
FromPort: '80'
ToPort: '80'
CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
Description: 'ALB will redirect HTTP to HTTPS'
VpcId: !Ref VPC

```
ApplicationLoadBalancer:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
  Properties:
    IpAddressType: ipv4
    Name: !Join ["-", [!Ref Environment, !Ref AppNameForResources, "server"]]
    Scheme: internal
    LoadBalancerAttributes:
    - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
      Value: '30'
    SecurityGroups:
      - !Ref SecurityGroupForALB
    Subnets:
      - Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub
          - "${TheNetworkStackName}-PrivateAZ1-ID"
          - TheNetworkStackName: !Ref NetworkStackName
      - Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub
          - "${TheNetworkStackName}-PrivateAZ2-ID"
          - TheNetworkStackName: !Ref NetworkStackName
      - Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub
          - "${TheNetworkStackName}-PrivateAZ3-ID"
          - TheNetworkStackName: !Ref NetworkStackName
    Type: application

ALBTargetGroup:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    Name: !Sub '${Environment}-${AppNameForResources}-alb-tg-1'
    HealthCheckEnabled: true
    HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
    HealthCheckPort: '80'
    HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
    HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
    HealthyThresholdCount: 2
    UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
    Port: '80'
    Protocol: !Ref LoadBalancerTargetGroupProtocol
    TargetType: ip
    VpcId:
      Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${NetworkStackName}-VPCID"

ALBListenerForHTTP:
  Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener"
  Properties:
    LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ApplicationLoadBalancer
    # Load balancer needs to listen on port 80 for incoming HTTPS requests
    Port: 80
    Protocol: "HTTP"
    DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref ALBTargetGroup

ECSService:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  DependsOn: ALBListenerForHTTP
  Properties:
    ServiceName: !Sub ecs-service-${AWS::Region}-${ServiceName}-${Environment}
    Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
    TaskDefinition: !Ref ECSTaskDefinition
    DesiredCount: 1
    HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    LaunchType: FARGATE
    NetworkConfiguration:
      AwsvpcConfiguration:
        # change to DISABLED if you're using private subnets that have access to a NAT gateway
        AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
        Subnets:
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub
              - "${TheNetworkStackName}-PrivateAZ1-ID"
              - TheNetworkStackName: !Ref NetworkStackName
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub
              - "${TheNetworkStackName}-PrivateAZ2-ID"
              - TheNetworkStackName: !Ref NetworkStackName
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub
              - "${TheNetworkStackName}-PrivateAZ3-ID"
              - TheNetworkStackName: !Ref NetworkStackName
        SecurityGroups:
          - !Ref SecurityGroupForALB
    LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: !Sub
          - "${TheServiceName}-${TheEnvironment}"
          - TheServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
            TheEnvironment: !Ref Environment
        ContainerPort: 80
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref ALBTargetGroup
```

I've defined Subnets/VPC/Image etc in my dev.json file.
Appreciate if you could let me know what's wrong with the ECS::Service stack.

Thanks

Comment: You need to check the ECS console for the stopped tasks, and look at the reason they were stopped. You also need to check for any logs of the stopped containers in CloudWatch Logs. However it doesn't look like you have container logs enabled, so you will need to do that first. Enable logs, gather the stopped task details and any container logs, and then please edit your question to include those critical debugging details.

Comment: Thank you. I had to manually stop the task to kill the deployment process and I see this reason for the stopped tasks. Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:6655524664:targetgroup/dev-demo-ecs-poc-ui-alb-tg-1/57dd9be4e079e3a2)

Comment: Do I also need AWS::Batch::JobDefinition in my template? Bit confused when to use this...

Comment: You didn't mention AWS Batch in your question at all. An ECS Service is a completely different thing from an AWS Batch Job. An AWS Batch Job also doesn't use a Load balancer. You also generally wouldn't use Nginx with an AWS Batch Job.

Comment: Thank you very much for both questions. Yes I don't intent use batch job here but just came across when searching for answers. Will try setting up a new security group.

Answer (score 0):

Your security group doesn't allow any traffic at all, so your Load Balancer cannot connect to the ECS service. You have created a single security group, and assigned it to both the Load Balancer and the ECS Service. Assigning different types of resources to the same Security Group does not give those different resources access to each other. It is generally a bad practice to assign different types of resources to the same security group.

You need to create a separate security group for the ECS service, and add an inbound rule in that security group that allows traffic from the Load Balancer's security group.